# How to make bootstrap's dropdown menu not disappear when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for the first time. My question is about dropdown menu.
When the dropdown button is clicked, the dropdown menu is open. After clicking one dropdown item, the dropdown menu is closed.  Clicking anywhere in the window closes the dropdown menu too.

The question is:

I want to make the dropdown menu not to be closed when clicking the dropdown menu itself, because I want to nest another dropdown menu in it.

demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Action
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update your html with the nested dropdown and try reproducing the issue?

Comment: I guess this is what you are trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/yxkut/16/ Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ranjana  That is what I want,thanks a lot!

Comment: – @Ranjana ,  there is a question about sub-menu, I open level-1 menu first,and then open sub-menu.and then click in the window but not on sub-menu,at this time,all of the menus are closed.   Now, I open the level-1 menu again, sub-menu(s) is/are still open,I want it/them(sub-menu(s)) to be not open,how to do it?

Comment: You can try this - http://jsfiddle.net/YXkUT/1711/ Added few lines of js.

Comment: @Ranjana Thanks again! In my specific program，two levels is necessary, level-3 and level-4 are not needed this time,and, I want to make level-2 sub-menu hide when there is a mouseleave() event on level-2 sub-menu, how to do it? PS:Level-1 menu does't need this event.

Comment: May this help you - http://jsfiddle.net/YXkUT/1719/

Comment: @Ranjana Thanks again!That's what I want.